# GWT and JSNI: third-party library integration

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I'm trying to integrate [Opentip](http://www.opentip.org) into a GWT project. Since some of my widgets are loaded from Java instead of the HTML, it seems like I'll have to use JSNI to get those tooltips bound properly. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Put the relevant JS/CSS declarations before GWT's `nocache.js` in my HTML file. (I also tried duplicating the JS loading by using `ScriptInjector`, but that didn't do any good, so I ripped it out as redundant.
2. Written a JSNI method to instantiate the tooltips:

   ```
   private native void initControlTooltips() /*-{
       var headerText = "Tooltip text";
       new $wnd.Opentip($("#tooltipTrigger"), headerText);
       // more tooltips...
   }-*/
   ```

I've tried different variants of the above method, but I've read that this is the way it's supposed to work (Slide 20 [here](http://www.slideshare.net/martyhall/gwt-tutorial-using-jsni-the-javascript-native-interface), though I can't link directly to the slide). So far I've had no luck, and this most recent attempt, which seems the most correct to me, has actually stopped the rest of my GWT module from loading (after the tooltip instantiation call), as if I have a syntax error somewhere, though the console isn't reporting anything. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I'm relatively new to both GWT and JS, so I'm hoping this is just a stupid beginner's mistake.

The one thing I haven't tried yet is coding up an [Overlay object](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html), partially because I can't see from the docs how to properly wrap a JS constructor. If that's the solution here, some pointers on how to do that would be welcome. As a reference, the constructor I'd be using (from the Opentip documentation) is:

```
new Opentip("#my-trigger-element", "Optional content", "Optional title", { ...options... });
```

Thanks for any help; this doesn't seem like it should be that tough of a problem, but so far my inexperience has foiled my efforts.

**Update**

After several hours of cursing and parameter fiddling, I've resolved this, so don't waste any time trying to help me debug. I'll write up an answer a little later today when I get a bit of free time.

Comment: Have you tried any Opentip functionality in pure html+js? Maybe you can do some simple example on your index.html page, without even loading GWT.

Comment: I've tried that, and in fact that's what I'd rather do, but I'm trying to put tooltips on widgets that are instantiated and loaded by GWT, so Opentip's binding (which runs on document.ready(), I believe) doesn't pick them up, even if I have GWT add the Opentip-specific html to the new widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got your `web.gwt.xml`, your module, and your `EntryPoint` all set up. If you don't have those things, this isn't the answer for you. [The documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) isn't a bad place to start. This answer will use Opentip as an example, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for others too; specifically, though, this is geared for if you have widgets set up solely in GWT (not accessible from your HTML) and need to bind your external JS to them to enable some functionality.

1. Crack open your `web.gwt.xml` and make sure you're including your library's source in the entry for the module where you want to use it. This means that you don't have to declare it in your page's static HTML if you don't specifically need it there as well.

   ```
   <script src="../js/opentip/opentip-jquery.min.js"/>
   ```

   (Note the `../` - this is a relative path from where your GWT-generated HTML file ends up on your server, and it has to be accessible by your web server.)
2. In the module class where you want to use the library, rig up a JSNI method, calling your library constructor like so:

   ```
   private native void initTooltip() /*-{
       new $wnd.Opentip($doc.getElementById("tooltipTrigger"), "Tooltip text");
   }-*/;
   ```

   (Note the `$wnd` for referring to the top-level window and the `$doc` for referring to the document. Prepending `$wnd.` works for referring to any global variables declared/assigned in external JS files.)

No fancy Overlay types or `ScriptInjector` calls needed. I did have one other problem while working this out - my call to `getElementById()` was coming back `null` - this turned out to be because I was calling my JSNI method before the relevant object had been added to the DOM during `onModuleLoad()`.

Like I thought initially, this turned out to be a simple beginner's mistake; hope this can help someone else trying to piece together other answers to similar questions into a workable solution for their problem.